# Disable automatic closing parenthesis in Visual Studio / Resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper, resharper-10.0

Visual Studio 2015 with Resharper 10 here. And a very annoying behaviour I have no idea how to get rid of:

If I type this for example

```
Thread.Sleep(
```

I get the intellisense list as expected. I then move the selection bar down to `TimeSpan.FromMinutes` with the cursor down key and hit enter.

Result:

```
Thread.Sleep( TimeSpan.FromMinutes);
```

*Question*: what can I do to *not* get the **);** inserted automatically?

Options that I turned off already:

in VS:

- `Automatic brace completion`

in Resharper:

- `Auto-insert pair brackets, parentheses and quotes`
- `Auto-insert closing brace`
- `Automatically insert parentheses after completion`

Comment: No solution but I'm right there with you on the annoyance factor. I'll keep an eye out for answers.

Comment: Hmm, when I press Enter after cursoring down to TimeSpan.FromMinutes, I get `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes());` with the caret positioned inside the `()` ready for me to type the parameter. (Resharper Ultimate version 2016.1.2)